# Learning designing a Arduino pcb, doubt about USB traces

Tags: arduino, pcb, usb, design, trace

what consideration should I have for the USB section. How do correctly the usb traces? What means this curves?

This is my reference [schematic](https://easyeda.com/editor#id=a386d34bf22a4823b6cfb5264afd4e30) and [due board](https://easyeda.com/editor#id=859529a58f57416e9e6b64d4a8f1df9e).

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't use that board as an example of how to do USB properly.  It's a real mess.  There are many documents online that will give you a straightforward explanation of the requirements, search for something like "USB2.0 PCB layout design guide".

Comment: What are the chips the 2 sets of USB are going to? Their datasheet will give recommendations regarding length of signals, termination resistors, etc.

Comment: ATMEGA16U2-MU ATSAM3X8EA-AU

Comment: The following design guidelines should be met:
 Serial resistors on USB Data lines must have 22 Ohms value (+/- 5%).
Traces from the input USB receptacle (or from the cable connection in the case of a tethered
device) to the USB microcontroller pads should be as short as possible, and follow differential
traces routing rules (same length, as near as possible and avoid vias accumulation).
• Voltage transient / ESD suppressors may also be used to prevent USB pads to be damaged
by external disturbances.
Ucap capacitor should be 1μF (+/- 10%) for correct operation.